# Why is my model flickering when rendering?

Tags: rendering

I created a model in SketchUp and exported it as a .dae file.

[image: SketchUp Model]

Then I imported the .dae file into Blender and created an animation with it.

[image: Blender View]

However, when I render the video, the model looks like it is flickering (as can be seen in the top-left window below).
Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this? Your help is greatly appreciated!